Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError in Flutter while compressing image using flutter_image_compress
I'm trying to compress an image in flutter that I'm clicking from the camera. After which I'm uploading the image to supabase storage bucket.
The code was working fine before adding the compression functionality. But after the compression function, I'm getting the following error and I'm unable to upload the files anymore.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError
#0      UnsupportedFlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile (package:flutter_image_compress_platform_interface/flutter_image_compress_platform_interface.dart:116:5)
#1      FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile (package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart:105:22)
#2      FileManagement.compressImage (package:aller_vision_tech/utils/files.dart:25:60)
#3      FileManagement.onCaptureButtonPressed (package:aller_vision_tech/utils/files.dart:37:41)
<asynchronous suspension>

I'm unable to understand the error and not able to debug as well. Please help me out.
The whole code file looks like this,
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:aller_vision_tech/main.dart';
import 'package:aller_vision_tech/pages/results.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class FileManagement {
    Future<XFile?> compressImage(File file) async {
      final filePath = file.absolute.path;
      final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(RegExp(r'.png|.jp'));
      final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
      final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

      if (lastIndex == filePath.lastIndexOf(RegExp(r'.png'))) {
        final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
            filePath, outPath,
            minWidth: 1000,
            minHeight: 1000,
            quality: 50,
            format: CompressFormat.png);
        return compressedImage;
      } else {
        final compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          filePath,
          outPath,
          minWidth: 1000,
          minHeight: 1000,
          quality: 50,
        );
        return compressedImage;
      }
    }
  Future<void> onCaptureButtonPressed(CameraController cameraController, BuildContext context) async {
    final XFile captured_image = await cameraController.takePicture();
    final XFile compressedImage = await compressImage(File(captured_image.path)) as XFile;
    final File imageFile = File(compressedImage.path);
    User? user = supabase.auth.currentUser;

    final bytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final fileExt = imageFile.path.split('.').last;
    final fileName = '${user?.id}_${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.$fileExt';
    final filePath = fileName;

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScanResultsPage(scanImgName: fileName)));

    try {
      await supabase.storage.from('bucket_name').uploadBinary(
        filePath,
        bytes,
        fileOptions: FileOptions(contentType: 'image/$fileExt'),
      );

      //final String signedUrl = await supabase.storage.from('imgscans').createSignedUrl(fileName, 60);
    } on StorageException catch (error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(error.message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        ),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Catch Error: ${error.toString()}'),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}

I have tried to upgrade the pubspec file.
Tried running flutter pub upgrade and nothing happened.
I checked for async-await mistakes. Still the same error.

Hey @ChaoticQubit, Close the app and try running the app again.
